# Ldap query to get users of a group in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to write a filter to get all the users of a given group in Active Directory.

To that end I have the following query

```
LDAPSearch("DC=test,DC=myorg,DC=com", "(objectClass=user)", 1, "name")
```

I'm a bit confused as to where I should give the name of the group on which to base the search on. As far as I know you cannot have two groups in AD with the same name.

Comment: You give it where you specified `"DC=test,DC=myorg,DC=com"`.

Answer (score 0):

In general, user objects have an attribute called `memberOf` that lists DNs of groups that a user is member of. Therefore you can search with a filter like `(&(objectClass=user)(memberOf=<DN of requested group>))`.

Please note that due to AD design, user's primary group is not included in `memberOf` attribute. For most users that group would be `Domain Users` (unless explicitly changed), but if changed, that group will no longer list in `memberOf` and this query will not find such user.